# Transparent windows with Linux

Tags: c++, linux, transparency, x11, compiz

I am trying to find a  cross linux distribution solution to the problem of making a program have transparent windows.

I now there is some methods out there, that take screen shots of the windows underneath and then print them as the background of the image. I would prefer not to uses that method because it likely that i would have video running in the background of the program. But if any one knows of a good way to make this happen i would still be please to here about it.

I have tried to implement a method I found at :
[Changing X11 Windows Properties](http://www.space-out.net/readarticle.php?article=1)

I couldn't get any change to happen, though I am not sure if Compiz was working correctly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the code of the X terminal emulators, KTerm for KDE or Gnome Terminal for gnome (depending of your target platform). I think these are the best examples of apps that implement transparency. I think that you can even find in that code solutions for getting transparency when compiz is not available.

Comment: I was able to find my solution when looking at the the gnome terminal